# CakePHP: Auth Component not logging in

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm studying right now CakePHP, and I followed every direction they gave me there and I got wonderful results, but when it comes to the Auth Component (and the very simple authentication they teach at the site), I just can't manage to do it.

The method $this->Auth->login() keeps returning false, and not letting me log in.

I am not using anything more than the tutorial shows me, I'm not even hashing the passwords yet (Calm down, I will, but I need to get the basic before!).

Here goes my code:

**Model**

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class User extends AppModel {

public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'required' => true
        ),
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'required' => true
        ),
    ),
);
```

**AppController**

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {


public $components = array(

    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(

        'loginRedirect'  => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index')

        )

    );


}
```

**Users Controller**

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {

public function login()
{

    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        if(!$this->Auth->login())
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid Username or Password');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
    }


}

public function logout()
{

    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());

}
```

**View (Users/login.ctp)**

```
<div class="login-box">

<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>

<?php

    echo $this->Form->create();

    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');

    echo $this->Form->end('login');

?>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any validation errors?  What is displayed when you submit? Does it show your flash message?  Is it getting redirected?

Comment: Hmm, no validation errorr that I'm aware of. It displays that my user or pass is invalid, but they are not (and I'm not hashing them). And yes, it shows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to hash the password before saving it into the database. When authenticating using AuthComponent::login(), the password entered in your login form is first hashed and then checked with the entry in the database. As your entry in the database is not hashed, the check returns false.

Hash the password in User::beforeSave() as mentioned here in the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout).

Comment: Guys, can anyone upvote this guy? Seriously, they didn't mention that I was obrigated to always hash the password (I know the security issues, but for studying is kinda annoying, haha). Many thanks.

Comment: There IS a little line that mentions it, but - could be worded more clearly:  "You don’t need to hash passwords before calling $this->Auth->login(). The various authentication objects will hash passwords individually."